# Graphic randomization in Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I have a questionnaire and I want to have 8 photos randomised in 8 different questions so participants see a different photograph to one another with the question. Does anyone know how I can do this and can help? Many thanks

Comment: Do you want the respondents to see 1 question with 1 of 8 random photos or see 8 questions each with 1 of 8 random photos?  If the latter, is the question text different for each of the 8 questions?

Comment: I think you could Loop and merge over urls of your photos. It is describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811793/randomization-in-qualtrics-using-photos-or-graphics-and-loop-and-merge well.

Comment: One more tip: put names or ids of the image to the first field and url to the second field. The first field will be displayed in the name of the question in the output and having there urls is not practical.