# Performing randomization using java script on Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have 1000+ images and I need to randomize them before anybody takes my survey on Qualtrics? Thus, I want to know how should I implement the custom JavaScript for the randomization of images stored on the image library. Also is it possible to host the image on my dropbox and do the similar procedure. I have created the CSV file of all the images which are ordered from 1-1000, so if randomization needs to be performed over CSV please let me know about that.

FYY: I have no background in JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially read Why is [“Can someone help me?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) not an actual question?

Comment: What about [Loop and merge over images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470395/how-to-loop-over-hundreds-of-images-in-qulatrics-help-needed-to-implement-code) and just turn on randomization?