# Getting Qualtrics Graphics URLs

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, qualtrics

Following up with the code explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811793/randomization-in-qualtrics-using-photos-or-graphics-and-loop-and-merge/23964328#23964328), I'd like to scrape the URLs for a series of graphics in the Qualtrics graphics library. However, the code provided in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811793/randomization-in-qualtrics-using-photos-or-graphics-and-loop-and-merge/23964328#23964328) doesn't seem to work. I have one concrete issue and one intuition for why that is:

**Issue:** If I manually navigate to the photos library and then run the rest of the code (as instructed in the instructions), I get a message saying that

```
name 'driver' is not defined
```

I kind of solved this using `time.sleep(20)` and using the pause to log in to Qualtrics and navigate to the library. I am not sure if there are better ways of doing this.

**Intuition:** Once I solved the issue above, the code runs but there is nothing in the output. My intuition is that `find_elements_by_css_selector(".thumbframe")` doesn't work for Qualtrics' current design.

Anyway, it could be something else. Could someone help me out with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to do this is just copy and paste the image IDs from Qualtrics.  See: [How to loop over hundreds of images in Qulatrics - help needed to implement code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470395/how-to-loop-over-hundreds-of-images-in-qulatrics-help-needed-to-implement-code/42493715#42493715)